# How to investigate non-specific Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard errors

Tags: sql-server, ssms, scripting

I am trying to use the Generate and Publish Scripts wizard in SSMS 2012 against a 2012 SQL instance and am getting errors. Trying to generate a schema-only script of the tables and schemas. I allowed it to continue when there were errors. 50% of the tables fail, specifically in the Preparing table xxx and the result is error. The final result is failure.

This is a db on a test instance, the db on the prod instance (same-ish) works great. I only have db_datareader and db_datawriter on the instances. I cannot view the error log as a result, I cannot view the event log either. I am running ssms on a third server. Where can I get more info on the errors, if they are even in either log, and would they be on the instance servers or on the sssms server?